# Q: How to reset roles in WSO2 Identity Server?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have a primary LDAP user store pointing to Active Directory in user-mgt.xml. When I initially set it up I set the <AdminRole> setting to "everyone" as I was testing the configuration. Later, I switched this to a new AD group / role. I then went in and was reviewing the role permissions. The new role had all permissions but the "internal/everyone" role still had full admin permissions as well. I removed the permissions from internal/everyone and now I cannot sign-in on the Identity Server web interface with any account. How do I reset the roles so I can sign-in and only my AdminRole group has full admin access?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to two missing properties from the default read-only LDAP sample in user-mgt.xml when using Active Directory. Adding these two lines and restarting the server resolved the issue:

```
<Property name="BackLinksEnabled">true</Property>
<Property name="MemberOfAttribute">memberOf</Property>
```

This was mentioned in the post: [WSO2 -> Active Directory -> user - role mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26112719/wso2-active-directory-user-role-mapping)